# How to make Float Action Button infobox

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add an information box above the floataction button as in the image below. How can I do that? Thank u

[Image URL CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmcZX.png)

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Fab_Bottom_app_bar"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="15dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="60dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Fab_Bottom_app_bar"
            android:background="@drawable/dropbutton"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:backgroundTint="#2770DC"
        app:tint="#fff"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />
```

Comment: url doesn't work

Comment: try again please

Comment: that's what you need https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow

PopupWindow should serve your purpose

"This class represents a popup window that can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup window is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity."

You can pass whatever "contentView" you want to show into its constructor and call the "showAtLocation" method to determine where to show it.